# Is It Possible to Upsert Values in a Big Query Table with Composite Primary Key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy, orm

###### Context

Using python and sqlalchemy to insert some machine learning model inference to a big query table. This is how the table looks like (two sample rows).

[image]

And this is how the data types appear in BQ.

[image]

Basically, `demand_date` and `inference_date` are supposed to be composite primary key columns. To make the upsert idempotent, whenever I insert into this table using SQL-Alchemy, if the `demand_date` and `inference_date` combination already exists, I want to replace the old values in the `tcn` and `boosting` with new values using `session.merge` method of SQL alchemy.

###### Question

Is it even possible, with SQL alchemy? That is because recently I read that BQ cannot enforce primary key constraint, which means I will end up with duplicate rows? If not possible, what is the cleanest way to upsert in big query using SQL-alchemy interface?

Answer (score 1):

Bigquery has started providing SQL like constraints including primary key and foreign key.

**Primary Key**
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_primary_key_statement

**Foreign Key**
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_foreign_key_statement

For **upsert** Bigqury also providers **merge** statement.  What you are trying to do is called maintaining SCD Type 1 table and merge statement would be perfect for that.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Comment: Thanks for the response the the documentation link. But seems the command itself says the primary key constraints are not enforced.

Comment: yes, my bad. like most big data database, it's just a suggestion, not enforced as it would be too difficult to do that for distributed database.  however, `merge` statement will do what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. In that case, who is this _suggestion_ meant for and  where exactly is this visible?